# Pseudo-Element: Vertical inline alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I want to use `::before` to achieve some kind of inline prefix for a `<span>`-tag.
This Prefix should have the same dimensions (padding-top and padding-bottom) as the `<span>` but a different background-color.

When floating it to the left, it's slightly shifted and creates a little white space above the pseudo-element. All approaches I found here on SO mentioned to set the `vertical-align: bottom` but it doesn't work.

If I place two `<span>`-tags next to each other everything works but I want to use the pseudo-element since I only need one `<span>`-tag and the CSS is cleaner.

HTML

```html
<span>Some text I want to have here.</span>
```

SCSS

```css
span {
   background-color: #ebebeb;
   padding: .5em .2em .5em .2em;

   &::before {
       content: "Prefix:\00a0";
       background-color: #d1d1d1;
       padding: .5em .2em .5em .2em;
       float: left;
   }
}
```

See Demo: http://codepen.io/to7be/pen/yVJYaW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removing the `float: left` makes it look good:

[image: preview]

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmjvEQ**

Vertical alignment doesn't work on floated elements.

If you don't want that small little space on the left, you can do a `margin-left: -2px;`:

[image: preview]

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBeVQJ**

Comment: At first I thought so, too. But on the very left there is a little light-gray area growing with the <span>'s padding.

Good to know that vertical-align on floated elements doesn't work!!

Comment: @to7be Did you check the full answer? *If you don't want that small little space on the left, you can...* **Reload buddy!** There are two images and two codes.